# Colorless commander using lands that chose based upon identity?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander, mtg-color-identity

**TLDR**

- Can I use lands that mention "color identity" with a colorless commander while still getting their bonus effects?

I apologize if I have missed something that explains this situation, but I am unsure how the rules work around my planned commander: [Kozilek, the Great Distortion](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Kozilek%2C%20the%20Great%20Distortion).

With this as my commander if I used a card such as [Opal Palace](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Opal%20Palace) that reads

> [image: {1}], [image: {T}]: Add to your mana pool one mana of any color in your commander's color identity. If you spend this mana to cast your commander, it enters the battlefield with a number of additional +1/+1 counters on it equal to the number of times it's been cast from the command zone this game.

As I understand the rules any cards in your deck must have your commander's color. Colorless is not a color. Therefore, does the colorless indicator or the Wastes indicator count as my commander's color identity?

Would the case be similar if I used a land such as [Exotic Orchard](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Exotic%20Orchard)? I realize technically those are two different questions, but I think they are similar and easily answered within the same frame of reference...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The rulings under the card in Gatherer say

> If your commander is a card like Kozilek, Butcher of Truth that has no colors in its color identity, Opal Palace’s last ability produces no mana.

That means you can use it in your deck but it won't produce the desired effect.

Exotic Orchard has no colors in its color identity and can be used as well, and it works [just as it would in a normal 2 player game](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/32145/12315), i.e. it can be used to produce blue mana if your opponent controls an Island.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. I'm an idiot. No wonder I couldn't find a question describing my situation.... because everybody else read that listing... thank you.